# summarize the total of number of "days+hours:min" the user logged in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a sample logs below

```
user02|(1+08:12)
user01|(00:00)
user01|(08:55)
user01|(2+09:13)
user02|(2+10:31)
user01|(04:25)
user01|(07:59)
user01|(07:59)
user01|(08:45)
user01|(00:10)
user02|(09:11)
user01|(04:49)
user01|(-7:-59)
user02|(-1:-31)
```

I want to add all the time for every different user:
the output should be the total time format days+hours:min:
sample output:

```
user01 4+13:12
user02 2:09
```

I hope you guys can help me solve this thank in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail? Is a Perl solution an absolute requirement?

Comment: it was actually an exercise in perl, my Sir gave me a hint to use Data::calc

Comment: Well, SO is not a page full of people who do your your exercises for you. You will have to do it yourself and then, if you encounter any specific problems, you can ask for help.

Comment: Hmm, i might have been wrong, apparently there are people on SO who do want to do your exercises for you instead of answering questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I understood it is for educational purpose, I will give you a partial solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @log = ( 'user02|(1+08:12)',
'user01|(00:00)',
'user01|(08:55)', ... # supposing you loaded your data into an array

my %hash = (); # using an empty hash

foreach my $line (@log) { # iteranting each line
  $line =~ /^(user\d+)/; # searching for "userXXXX" pattern
  my $user = $1; # assigning matched value to $user

  # figure out how to act on $hash{ $user } :)
}
```

Have a general look [here](http://search.cpan.org/~stbey/Date-Calc-6.3/lib/Date/Calc.pod) to understand how to use **Date::Calc** then focus your attention on function's names containing **Delta**.

I hope you will learn and understand something new starting from this.

Don't forget to post the solution ;)